# Ровно k фишек на доске

Tags: c++

В каждую крайнюю клетку квадратной доски поставили по фишке. Могло ли оказаться, что выставлено ровно k фишек? (Например, если доска 2 x 2, то выставлено 4 фишки, а если 6 x 6 - то 20).

Вводится одно натуральное число k.

Comment: >Могло ли оказаться, что выставлено ровно k фишек?

Могло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как сказано "в каждую", то кол-во можно легко рассчитать. Пусть `n` - размер стороны поля. Тогда всех крайних клеток будет `4n-4` (это легко увидеть, если считать, что каждая угловая клетка принадлежит одной стороне). Поэтому проверочный код будет такой.

```
if (k < 4) {
    cout << "очень мало фишек" << endl;
    return 1;
}
if (k % 4 != 0) {
   cout << "нельзя занять все клетки этим кол-вом фишек" << endl;
   return 2;
}
cout << "все можно сделать, это будет квадрат со стороной " << (k / 4) + 1 << endl;
return 0;
```

ввод-вывод и остальной код думаю сможете дописать.